# Replace multiple values in one cell

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to replace all the long names with codes. Some cells have 20 or more of that long names and i prefer the codes.

I have two dataframes:

**Result**

```
Number   Omschrijving  functie
102040   Kadaster      Grondwerker Landmeter
104510   Graven sleuf  Stratenmaker Grondwerker Landmeter
```

**Functiecode**

```
functie        code
Stratenmaker   F1
Grondwerker    F3
Landmeter      F17
```

Expected output:

**df**

```
Number   Omschrijving  functie
102040   Kadaster      F3 F17
104510   Graven sleuf  F1 F3 F17
```

Because in the column functie there more than one strings, i don't know how to fix this.

I tried `subset`, `rbind`, `cbind` and `merge` but the output is not what I need .

---

Data:

```
Result <- read.table(text = "
Number,Omschrijving,functie
102040,Kadaster,Grondwerker Landmeter
104510,Graven sleuf,Stratenmaker Grondwerker Landmeter
", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

Functiecode <- read.table(text = "
functie        code
Stratenmaker   F1
Grondwerker    F3
Landmeter      F17
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split on space `" "`, then replace with *lookup*:

```
lookup <- setNames(Functiecode$code, Functiecode$functie)

Result$functie <- lapply(strsplit(Result$functie, " "), function(i){
  paste(lookup[ i ], collapse = " ")
})

Result
#   Number Omschrijving   functie
# 1 102040     Kadaster    F3 F17
# 2 104510 Graven sleuf F1 F3 F17
```